# cancancan automatically call my permitted params method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

```
class ProgramsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index; end

  def new; end

  def create
    if @program.save
      redirect_to programs_path, notice: 'Program created successfully'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy; end

  private

  def program_params
    params.require(:program).permit(
      :name,
      :program_type,
      :size,
      :date_start,
      :date_renewal,
      :date_due,
      :duration,
      :supplier_max_limit,
      :kibor_rate,
      :bank_spread,
      :status,
      :creator_id
    )
  end
end
```

> > In in the above code I understand the on new and index, the @program will populate automatically by cancancan.. But in case of create method, the **program_params** is **automatically called**.. I didn't call the **program_params** anywhere in my code and if I change the name of the **program_params** method to something else, it is not called.. does cancancan is dealing with this ?
> > please give me some explanation on this. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cancancan docs clearly state](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/controller_helpers.md#strong-parameters) that this is expected behavior for `load_and_authorize_resource`

> For the :create action, CanCanCan will try to initialize a new
> instance with sanitized input by seeing if your controller will
> respond to the following methods (in order):
>
> 1. create_params
> 2. <model_name>_params such as article_params (this is the default
>    convention in Rails for naming your param method)
> 3. resource_params (a generic named method you could specify in each controller)

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed that part in the documentation.